# How does phpinfo() change the title of the page permanently?

Tags: php

If you use phpinfo() in your page, you will notice it will change the title of your page? And even if you give the title of your page to be different it will not change. How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is because phpinfo print `<title>`, is depend on how browser handle the tag rendering.
Chrome, Firefox and internet explorer is practicing FIFO.

So, do this

```
<title>my title</title>
<?phpinfo() ?>
```

is `my title` being set as browser page title

```
<?phpinfo() ?>
<title>my title</title>
```

Then above will set page title to `phpinfo()`

Answer (score 1):

`phpinfo` outputs a complete HTML page, including a `<head>` section with `<title>phpinfo()</title>`. You can only have one `<head>` and one `<title>` per page, so I wouldn't even know how you'd attempt to change the title to anything else without producing a completely broken page to begin with.

Comment: in case you have some <title> tag and place phpinfo() after your <body>, your title tag is not disturbed.

Comment: @nepsdotin That depends entirely on how the browser interprets an HTML page within an HTML page. It may discard everything before the second `<html>` as noise, or it may not. Putting almost anything besides `phpinfo` into a file is bound to give you undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

put `<title>` tag above `phpinfo()`. Check the page source there will be two title tags , first one will be shown.